# What does aligning with the Brotherhood or Resistance do?

Tags: sanctuary-rpg

While exploring I occasionally come across pamphlets which, upon reading, give you a choice that will push your alignment towards one of these factions. At the start of the game it explains that all weapons are aligned to either of these factions, or are neutral, and equipping a weapon that matches your alignment gives you a 20% attack bonus, but other than that, what does faction alignment do? Does it affect the story in any way?